# ER diagram that implements a database for trainee

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I edited and remade the ERD. I have a few more questions.

I included participation constraints(between trainee and tutor), cardinality constraints(M means many), weak entities (double line rectangles), weak relationships(double line diamonds), composed attributes, derived attributes (white space with lines circle), and primary keys.

**Questions:**

1. Apparently to reduce redundant attributes I should only keep primary keys and descriptive attributes and the other attributes I will remove for simplicity reasons. Which attributes would be redundant in this case? I am thinking **start_date, end_date, phone number, and address** but that depends on the entity set right? For example the attribute address would be removed from Trainee because we don't really need it?
2. For the part: "For each trainee we like to store (if any) also previous companies (employers) where they worked, **periods of employment: start date and end date.**"

Isn't "periods of employment: start date, end date" a composed attribute? because the dates are shown with the symbol ":" Also I believe I didn't make an attribute for **"where they worked"** which is location?

Also how is it possible to show previous companies (employers) when we already have an attribute employers and different start date? Because if you look at the **Question Information** it states start_date for employer twice and the second time it says start_date and end_date.

3. I labeled many attributes as primary keys but how am I able to distinguish from derived attribute, primary key, and which attribute would be redundant?
4. Is there a multivalued attribute in this ERD? Would salary and job held be a multivalued attribute because a employer has many salaries and jobs.
5. I believe I did the participation constraints (there is one) and cardinality constraints correctly. But there are sentences where for example "An instructor teaches at least a course. Each course is taught by only one instructor"; how can I write the cardinality constraint for this when I **don't have** a relationship between course and instructor?
6. Do my relationship names make sense because all I see is "has" maybe I am not correctly naming the actions of the relationships? Also I believe schedules depend on the actual entity so they are weak entities.... so does that make course entity set also a weak entity (I did not label it as weak here)?
7. For the company address I put a composed attribute, street num, street address, city... would that be correct? Also would street num and street address be primary keys?
8. Also I added the **final mark** attribute to courses and course_schedule is this in the right entity set? The statement for this attribute is "Each trainee identified by: unique code, social security number, name, address, a unique telephone number, **the courses attended and the final mark for each course**."
9. For this part: "We store in the database all classrooms available on the site" do i make a composed attribute that contains site information?

[image]

**Question Information:**

A **trainee** may be self-employed or employee in a company

**Each trainee identified by**:
unique code, social security number, name, address, a unique
telephone number, the courses attended and the final mark for each course.

If the **trainee** is an **employee in a company**: store the current company (employer), start date.

For each trainee we like to store (if any) also previous companies (employers) where they worked, periods of employment: start date and end date.

If a trainee is self-employed: store the area of expertise, and title.

For a trainee that works for a company: we store the salary and job

For each company (employer): name (unique), the address, a unique telephone number.

We store in the database all known companies in the
city.

We need also to represent the courses that **each trainee is attending.**

Each course has a **unique code and a title.**

**For each course we have to store:** the classrooms, dates, and times (start time, and duration in minutes) the course is held.

**A classroom is characterized by** a building name and a room number and the maximum places’ number.

**A course is given** in at least a classroom, and may be scheduled in many classrooms.

We store in the database all classrooms
available on the site.

We store in the database all courses given at least once in the company.

**For each instructor we will store:** the social security number, name, and birth date.

An instructor teaches at least a course.

Each course is taught by only one instructor.

All the instructors’ telephone numbers must also be stored (each instructor has at least a telephone number).

A trainee can be a tutor for one or many trainees for a specific
period of time (start date and end date).

For a trainee it is not mandatory to be a tutor, but it is mandatory to have a tutor

Comment: Could you provide another link to your diagram? The one you provided doesn't seem to be working.  Perhaps you could add a link to the full questions as well because are a little confusing as to what you specifically need.  As far as Primary Keys are concerned, you can have any Unique field be specified as the Primary key. You can even have the conjunction of several fields together be your PK, but I would suggest not having fields such as telephone numbers be set to the PK, because these can change and even if they're unique changing a PK attribute can cause you more pains than you'd want.

Comment: I reattached a new link. It works for me, it should be working now. I can post the full question if you want but i have not yet reached it because I am new to databases and my knowledge is not up to date with the whole question but i will repost the whole question.

Comment: Also concerning the primary key problem, so a primary key for trainee would be the attribute 'code'? because it never changes?

Comment: I'm able to access it now, thanks.  If I had to make an assumption, yes 'code' would be the trainee's PK because it looks as if it is only there to be an unique Identifier.  I will post an answer soon with as much help as I can discern from your questions, but it may take a minute. bare with me.

Comment: Alright that was my answer to question 1. Thanks, Now my main problem is connecting the relationships as seen from above questions im not sure if I wrote the correct relationship for the entity set self-employed and employed. Also im not sure what relationship the entity set 'Company' has.

Comment: Also I'm supposed to show the constraints but ignore that because I know how to do that is the easy part.

Comment: please don't keep changing your question - it makes the answers make less sense and it becomes very difficult for future readers to understand when you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The attribute ‘Code’ will be your PK because it’s only use seems to be that of a Unique Identifier.
2. The relationship ‘is’ will work but having a reference to two tables like that can get messy.  Also you have the reference to "Employers" in the Trainee table which is not good practice. They should really be combined. See my helpful hints section to see how to clean that up.
3. Company looks like the complete table of Companies in the area as your details suggest.  This would mean table is fairly static and used as a reference in your other tables.  This means that the attribute ‘employer’ in Employed would simply be a Foreign Key reference to the PK of a specific company in Company. You should draw a relationship between those two.
4. It seems as though when an employee is ‘employed’ they are either an Employee of a company or self-employed.
5. The address field in Company will be a unique address your current city, yes, as the question states the table is a complete list of companies in the city. However because this is a unique attribute you must have specifics like street address because simply adding the city name will mean all companies will have the same address which is forbidden in an unique field.

Some other helpful hints:

Stay away from adding fields with plurals on them to your diagram. When you have a plural field it often means you need a separate table with a Foreign Key reference to that table. For example in your Table Trainee, you have ‘Employers’.  That should be a Employer table with a foreign key reference to the Trainee Code attribute.  In the Employer Table you can combine the Self-employed and Employed tables so that there is a single reference from Trainee to Employer.

[ERD Link http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1014217878605](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1014217878605). Here's a quick ERD I created for you. Note the use of linker tables to prevent Many to Many relationships in the table. It's important to note there are several ways to solve this schema problem but this is just as I saw your problem laid out. The design is intended to help with normalization of the db. That is prevent redundant data in the DB. Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more clarification on the design I provided. It should be fairly self explanatory when comparing your design parameters to it.

Follow Up Questions:

1. If you are looking to reduce attributes that might be arbitrary perhaps phone_number and address may be ones to eliminate, but start and end dates are good for sorting and archival reasons when determining whether an entry is current or a past record.
2. Yes, periods_of_employment does not need to be stored as you can derive that information with start and end dates.  Where they worked I believe is just meant to say previous employers, so no location but instead it’s meant that you should be able to get a list all the employers the trainee has had. You can get that with the current schema if you query the employer table for all records where trainee code equals requested trainee and sort by start date.  The reason it states start_date twice is to let you know that for all ‘previous’ employers the record will have a start and end date. Hence the previous.  However, for current employers the employment hasn't ended which means there will be no end_date so it will null.  That’s what the problem was stating in my opinion.
3. To keep it simple PK’s are unique values used to reference a record within another table. Redundant values are values that you essentially don’t need in a table because the same value can be derived by querying another table. In this case most of your attributes are fine except for Final_Mark in the Course table. This is redundant because Course_Schedule will store the Final_Mark that was received. The Course table is meant to simply hold a list of all potential courses to be referenced by Course_Schedule.
4. There is no multivalued attributes in this design because that is bad practice Job and salary are singular and if and job or salary changes you would add a new record to the employer table not add to that column. Multivalued attributes make querying a db difficult and I would advise against it. That’s why I mentioned earlier to abstract all attributes with plurals into their own tables and use a foreign key reference.
5. You essentially do have that written here because Course_Schedule is a linker table meaning that it is meant to simplify relationships between tables so you don’t have many to many relationships.
6. All your relationships look right to me. Also since the schedules are linker tables and cannot exist without the supporting tables you could consider them weak entities.  Course in this schema is a defined list of all courses available so can be independent of any other table. This by definition is not a weak entity. When creating this db you’d probably fill in the course table and it probably wouldn’t change after that, except rarely when adding or removing an available course option.
7. Yes, you can make address a composite attribute, and that would be right in your diagram.  To be clear with your use of Primary key, just because an attribute is unique doesn’t make it a primary key. A table can have one and only one primary key so you must pick a column that you are certain will not be repeated. In this example you may think street number might be unique but what if one company leaves an address and another company moves into that spot. That would break that tables primary key.  Typically a company name is licensed in a city or state so cannot be repeated. That would be a better choice for your primary key.  You can also make composite primary keys, but that is a more advanced topic that I would recommend reading about at a later date.
8. Take final_mark out of courses. That’s table will contain rows of only courses, those courses won’t be linked to any trainee except by course_schedule table. The Final_Mark should only be in that table.  If you add final_mark to Course table then, if you have 10 trainees in a course, You’d have 10 duplicate rows in the course table with only differing final_marks. Instead only hold the course_code and title that way you can assign different instructors, trainees and classrooms using the linker tables.
9. No composite attribute is needed using this schema. You have a Classroom table that will hold all available classrooms and their relevant information.  You then use the Classroom_Schedule linker table to assign a given Classroom to a Course_Schedule. No attributes of Classroom can be broken down to simpler attributes.

Comment: Ok i will read this and i will later upload a new ER diagram of my version

Comment: Because of the design parameters you provided. (sorry there should be 'Salary' and 'Job' attributes in Employer table as well) You said, "If a trainee is self-employed: store the area of expertise, and title" Therefore, if area of expertise and title are not null then we know the Trainee is self-employed. You also state, "For a trainee that works for a company: we store the salary and job" Therefore, if salary and job are not null then the trainee is an employee of a company.  That way you can store both in one table and can filter out based on the fields.

Comment: What relationship name would employer and company have?

Comment: I just think there should be another entity set because employee and employer are two different entity sets

Comment: Hey, i see you edited your ERD thanks for that. I will be working on my diagram once i am done i will upload it here. It might not be anytime around now but when i will upload it will you be able to help me with it? It might not be today but it will be soon because im going to make it as detailed as i can.

Comment: Absolutely. That's what this community is for. We'd love to help you perfect and better understand your project. I'll make sure to check this thread for updates through the next couple days. I live and work in Hawaii so keep that in mind if I don't respond immediately. (2 hours behind Pacific Time)

Comment: Regarding the Employer to Company relationship. An Employer 'has' a Company.  Also a Company and be 'Many' Employers. AKA a Company can be the Employer of many.

Comment: Hi Grim Coder, thanks for the reply and spending your time to help me. I appreciate it very much, i edited the ERD maybe it makes a little more sense now but I still seem to have some problems.

Comment: Also, instead of making a entity set such as course_Schedule shouldn't I make a relationship with a descriptive attribute in it? When would descriptive attributes in a relationship be necessary?

Comment: In linker tables there typically aren't many if at all descriptive attributes. That's why they're called linker tables. You're using them to link two tables that contain descriptive attributes together.  necessitating descriptive attributes is really up to the designer. If you feel the table and/or relationship wouldn't make sense without them. For instance Final_Mark is in Course_Schedule because that is where you'd add new relationships between trainee and course.

Comment: Alright that makes perfect sense. Now i understand what primary keys are and when they are necessary. I see the primary keys are used to track entity sets such as the primary key for trainee is in almost every entity set to control 1 certain trainee for it to be uniquee.  Also concerning the cardinality constraint should I include a constraint for Employers and Company relationship? Even though the question didn't mention that it is still obvious of what the constraint would be.

Comment: Also would the attribute "Birth_Date" be redundant for the Instructors entity set? It's not really descriptive because an instructors birth_date doesnt matter for courses or telephone_num. Would adding more constraints be neccesary because for trainee and trainee_Schedule i didnt add constraints but should I?

Comment: Other than that, thanks a lot for your help. I am finally finished with this problem. I will probably post another problem later and @ your name if you don't mind.

Comment: Correct about PKs, geforce.  Regarding your Cardinality Q, when designing relational dbs adding more detail never hurts.  Regarding Birth_Date, it is not technically redundant because it’s not stored anywhere else in the db, but you’re right in saying that it isn't contextually useful so removing it won't theoretically hurt you. Regarding constraints on the linker tables, they are fairly simple so they shouldn't be necessary, but for good measure if you wanted to add NOTNULL constraints to all FK attributes that’d work. Glad to help. Feel free to @ me or shoot me an email. Found on my profile.

Comment: Alright thanks.  Also just one quick question, is it possible for me to make relationship like this: Trainee ENROLLED Course where ENROLLED has attributes: Course_Code(course enrolled in code), Instructor_Code, Course_Final_Mark (should it be Final_Mark or Course_Final_Mark)...

Comment: Also i will be posting a new question on different thread soon.

Comment: (follow up reply for the above msg) Because it just seems this ER Diagram is inefficent it requires a lot of extra attributes and entitys when maybe I can replace those extra entities by putting the linked table attributes in relationship attributes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096460/er-diagram-that-implements-actors-database     is the link for the other question I was talking about I can't @ your name for some reason.

Comment: You can't add attributes to a relationship in sql because all data is stored in the tables. If you wanted an attribute to define the relationship further I would suggest adding it to the Trainee_Scheduling or Course_Scheduling tables. That way you could get the nature of the relationship detail you are looking for.  You can define the Final_Mark as anything you want, but defining it as Course_Final_Mark gives more detail as to the attribute's use so I'd go with that.

Comment: This design is to try to reduced redundant data input. You could possibly make it simpiler by removing trainee_Scheduling and instead adding a trainee_code FK in Course_Scheduling to directly link those two tables instead. I'll take a look at your other question and get back to you.

Comment: Hey I recently redid the first question you answered from a couple of days ago. When you have time just take a look at my questions. They shouldn't be too hard to answer, only 2 questions I think I got everything else correct now.