# ER Diagram that implements Actors Database

Tags: database, entity-relationship, diagram

Note: This is a rough copy i didnt include constraints, weak entities, ..., etc yet. I still need to have a solid understanding of this question.

Questions:

1. To keep track of what theater company manages performer, what performer is in two theatre companies do i have to make a unique code for each entity set in other entity sets to keep track of them?
2. Can start_Location simply point to Place for the theatre company entity?
3. Can an Actor be Born in a place or does it have to have a attribute that points to place?
4. Do my relationships so far make sense?
5. Are there any redundant attributes such as Short_Descript in Plays?
6. Can i make an attribute in Place called "Town, State/Department/Province"? Or does it have to be a composed attribute?

Please note: I will be editing and updating my diagram if I have more questions and such...

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints.

ERD:

[image]

**Question Information:**

An actor is born in a place and he/she lives presently in a place (this information is mandatory).

We store in the database only the last known place where the actor lives.

We need the following information for an actor: actor number, actor name , date when actor was born, and date when actor died (check if died > born).

An actor is a performer, or/and a theater director.
We store for performer the date when he/she started to perform.

We store for theater director the date when starts his/her last employment as theater director

We consider in DBActors the following types of plays: drama, comedy and tragedy.

For each we like to store the following data: play’s number , play’s title , play’s short description , year when it was written ,date when it was first presented on stage(p_date_p, date).

For dramas we store also the drama type,name of the main positive character, and name of main negative character.

The drama type is one of the following:
“classical”, “medieval”, “renaissance”, “nineteenth-century”, “modern”, and
“contemporary”

For comedies we store the comedy type, the name of main
character , and the name of the second character

The comedy type is one of the following: “ancient mroman”, “ancient greek”, “farce”, “comedy of humors”, “comedy of manners”,
“commedia dell’arte”, and “theater of absurd”;

For tragedies we store the tragedy type(t_type, varchar(20)),and name of main
character

The tragedy type is one of the following: “Greek”, “Roman”, “Renaissance”, “Neo
-classical”, and “Modern”

A play is written by one or many dramatists
It is possible that we do not know the dramatist for certain plays.

We store in the database all known plays even if they were not performed (“closet plays”)

Some actors are also dramatists.

We store in the database all known mdramatists.

An actor is hired by a unique theater company at any timestamp

He/she will stay in the same company the whole year when he/she was hired.

We store in the database the year when he/she was hired by the theater company
(small integer)

It is possible that the actor changes the theater company where he/she is
working during his/her life many times. It is possible that an actor is hired by the same company many times in different years. He/she can perform in
one or many plays (at least one)

which are presented by theater companies.

It is possible that an actor is hired by a theater company and performs in a play presented by another theater company.

It is unusual but possible that the same performer plays in the same play
presented by different theater companies. A theater company performs/presents
one or many plays every year.

Same play can be performed by one or many distinct theater companies.

We like to store in the database the date when the play starts to be performed
by a theater company.

It is possible that the same play is performed by different theater companies starting at same date.

We need to store for a dramatist his/her dramatist number,his/her name.

A dramatist wrote one or many plays(at least one).

The information to be stored in the database for each theater company
is: theater company number,theater company name , date when the
theater company started.

For each theater company we store in the database
the first location (place) where the theater company started

There might be more than one theater company starting in the same place.

A theater company must hire at least one actor.

Each theater company has a unique theater director.
He/she starts his/her work at a specific date.

It is possible that the same theater company has different theater directors but at distinct times and the same theater director manages different
theater companies in distinct times(never at the same date).

It is possible that the same theater director manages the same
theater company at different dates.

The information to be stored for place is: place number, town and state/department/province, place country

Comment: @Grim Coder Here is the next question I am working on, the ER diagram is above

Comment: Oh goodness. I'm not sure this is a good fit for SO.

Comment: It seems like you either have way too much information, or way too many questions. Also, I don't think the `sql` tag fits, as this is just a diagram.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad.  You may feel you've paired down your information, but you've not narrowed it down enough.  Each one of your bullet points should be its own post.

Comment: Not really, I posted a similar one and someone helped me with it actually. If you guys are too lazy to suggest anything rather not even comment.

Comment: Also thanks very much buddy for voting to remove my post after all the typing and hard work I did.

Comment: I'm not trying to depreciate your hard work, rather, help you get the best answer.  Posting to SO is a hard business.  Check out [ask] for tips and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my responses to your questions:

1. Whenever you look at two tables and see a Many to Many relationship, you can solve the problem easily using a linker table. Also known as a junction table “is a database table that contains common fields from two or more other database tables within the same database. It is on the many side of a one-to-many relationship with each of the other tables. Junction tables are known under many names, among them cross-reference table, bridge table, join table, map table, intersection table, linking table, many-to-many resolver, link table, pairing table, transition table, crosswalk, associative entity or association table.” [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)  You saw me use these tables in your previous question.  In this case you are stating that an actor can be managed my many Theater Companies and A Theater Company and also manage many Actors. This is a many to many so if you created a link table in between those tables for every relastionship between the two you’d add a new row in the link table that only contains a theater Company id and an actor id.  If an actor was managed by many theater companies then you’d add several rows to the link table each holding the same actor id but each row having a different theater company’s id.
2. Yes, you can have start_Location point directly to place. This means that that Start_Location attribute must be a Foreign Key (FK) pointing the theater company to the Primary Key (PK) of the related Place record.
3. By all means an actor can be born in a place, but just like above, you need a column in Actor, that is a FK to the Place Table’s PK.  You could call this column Birth_Place and all it’d hold is the PK of the record in Place that relates to the actor’s birth place. This column would also need to be NOT NULL because all actor’s need a Birth_Place.
4. So far it seems like your diagram will work to solve this problem, yes.  Just see question 1’s answer for that follow up addition.
5. You’re getting good at removing redundancies. Your diagram looks good. The only suggestion, I’d make is why do you have a play table and then 3 separate play type tables?  Why not add them together in on Table called Play. It’d sit exactly where Play currently sits in your diagram and contain the same attributes it already does, but you also add the following:

   a. Type – Would be a string that you could place “Drama”, “Comedy”, or “Tradegy” in so you’d know exactly what type of play it is. Also this would allow you to add future play types to the plays table and not have to add a whole new table to the DB.

   b. Sub_Type – Would also be a string and hold the type that you currently have under the separate tables. They are all essentially the same attribute in each table and would just hold different type descriptors depending on the parent Type.

   c. Main_Character – Would be a string that holds the main character, because in your three separate tables, you have main characters. You’re just calling them 3 separate things. (get the direction I’m going in here? )

   d. Secondary_Character – Would be a string that holds the secondary character. You have a secondary character in your dramas and comedies, but non in your tradegies so in tradegy records this column would wind up being null. See what I did there? You now have one table where you used to have 4, and in that one table you can retrieve all the same information you had in those 4 separate tables. Hopefully that’ll make your life easier.
6. You can do whatever you like, but I’m assuming you mean by best practices and it would be generally considered best practice to separate this single attribute into it’s Simple attribute sub parts. I.E. make it a composed attribute.

Comment: Alright , thanks for the answers. I will look over the answers you suggested soon.

Comment: for 5. when you suggested type, sub_type... to be in entity set Play would Type be a entity set? or an attribute that has 3 attributes inside it. And then each attribute(comedy, tragedy, ...) would have more attributes in side them which are the type of each comedy, tradegy...?

Comment: Or would Type, Sub_Type, Main_Character, Secondary_Character be just attributes in the entity set Play

Comment: Correct, Type, Sub_Type, Main_Character, and Secondary_Character would all be just simple attributes in the Play entity.  for each new record the Type attribute, for instance, would only hold one string value. It would either hold Comedy, Drama, or Tragedy but not multiple. then based on the type value that was input, you'd have a subtype that's relevant to the parent type that was picked.

Comment: I see, so then making an extra attribute for comedy, ..., would not exist and also the sub_Type such as modern, medieval,... would also not exist it would just be treated as an input and based on the Type input there will be a sub_Type produced. But then how does the database know all these sub_Types? Because the question says to store these sub_Types.

Comment: Also I don't think the main_Character attribute would work properly because there is a Positive main _character, negative main_character which depends on the Type like for example the Tragedy stores 1 main_character where as Drama type stores 2 main_characters which are positive and negative main characters

Comment: I'm confused by the first part of your question. "making an extra attribute for comend, ..., would not exist and aslo the sub_Type such as moder, .., would also not exist"  Yes they will be inputs, I would suggest drop downs, the subtype would have it's avaiable options change based on the Type that was picked.  I didn't see that they needed to by stored. You could easily to that in a seperate subtype Table with a PK and then a name (two attributes). In this instance the Sub_Type column in the Play table would hold the FK reference to corresponding PK in Sub_Type Table.

Comment: That's why you'd look at the main and secondary character columns as more or less place holders. You'd need your logic to say that when The play type is drama the main_char is the Positive main char and the secondary_char is the negative. Then in a comedy,well that's self explanatory. And when you logic sees type of Tragedy it'll now that the main_char is main_char and the secondary_char column will be null because it isn't needed.  This would be fairly simple logic to complete via a switch statement or at the very least an if/else statement.

Comment: Alright, I will look into that. There is one problem... Under the definitions of for our ER model foreign key isn't defined (maybe its candidate key?)

Comment: Does that mean you can't use a foreign key? A canidate key would be a valid option. I'm not sure how you plan on implementing it but I'd just make the Sub_Type Name in the sub_Type table the PK/Candidate key and then use it a the FK in the the Play table.

Comment: I don't know but my solutions for both questions are definitely wrong now. Based on other people have told me it is too big and we haven't even covered anything about link tables or foreign keys and the solutions apparently using aggregation and stuff like that.

Comment: I will ask about foreign keys and see... also there is supposed to be aggregation in plays

Comment: Also apparently im not allowed to add entities that aren't in the question or entity sets

Comment: Either way I appreciate the help and knowledge... I will redesign both and will show you later.

Comment: Ok. unfortunately there are a lot of solutions to db design problems.  Sadly your design will be more efficient in a real world implementation then the way I see them trying to force implementation. BTW, something to note is FK's are part of the core of relational database constraints. They are used to ensure the integrity of table relationships and as the word relationships is what makes these types of dbs special I hope your teacher does cover them or allow their use in the near future. Good luck on your redesign. I'm sure you'll nail it. let me know if you have any other questions.